# Using str.split(expand=True) on DataFrame for massive data sets

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a data set of **~800,000,000 - 1,000,000,000 rows** that is read in as a DataFrame from a .txt type file.

This DataFrame is read in as a **single column** where I have to use a df[column_name].str.split(expand=True) to expand out each value. This gives a unique column to each value between a set of white space.

One caveat of this data set is that the number of values read into this single column **can vary** -- but if any values are 'missing' they are missing from the end of the sequence and not somewhere in between.

For example:

```
df_in

   0
0  123 203 113 32
1  555 22 155
2  670 12
```

and then using `df_out = df_in['0'].str.split(expand=True)`

```
df_out

    0    1     3      4
0   123  203   113    32
1   555  22    155    None
2   670  12    None   None
```

The problem is that this works well up until I get these huge data sets where I run into `MemoryError` issues.

Is there a way to handle these larger data sets? Maybe using MultiProcessing?

One note is that keeping the indices of the DataFrame is important.

Comment: Please share at least some of the data, and more of your program (see: [mcve]). Odds are there is a way to work around this.

Comment: why don't you split the rows into columns at reading the text file in the first place?